# Laravel, PHPUnit, docker-compose, and env variable precedence

Tags: laravel, docker

I'm running PHPUnit tests in a Laravel 8 app and running into a problem with loading environment variables in the right order. Currently running in docker-compose, and the container configuration contains this:

```
env_file:
  - local.env
```

and local.env contains

```
APP_ENV=local
```

In phpunit.xml:

```
<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing" force="true"/>
```

However, in the test I get the following:

```
$_ENV['APP_ENV'] => 'testing'
env('APP_ENV') => 'local'
$_SERVER['APP_ENV'] => 'local'
getenv('APP_ENV') => 'testing'
```

In `vlukas/dotenv`, server takes precendence in `/src/Repository/RepositoryBuilder:27`, and   `Illuminate\Support\Env:55` uses the default, but I need different behavior.

Is it possible to override Illuminate\Support\Env? How would I accomplish this? Is there another way of getting the right variables into my tests?

I was able to get it working by changing `Illuminate\Support\Env` like this:

```
$builder = RepositoryBuilder::createWithNoAdapters()
    ->addAdapter(EnvConstAdapter::class)
    ->addAdapter(ServerConstAdapter::class);
```

Could submit a change to Laravel, but is there another way?

---

Small context: we're using ParamStore in AWS to inject variables to our containers, so the server variable from docker-compose is the closest way to replicate that. Would rather not migrate to a .env file to keep consistency with the way the app is loaded in production.

Comment: For testing environment, the file `.env.testing` is used, you might try that.

Comment: Yep, still doesn't seem to work. The only way I've found so far is to change the `Env` class to reprioritize the order of environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `<server>` instead of `<env>` in your `phpunit.xml`, you did not upgrade correctly, see the [default `phpunit.xml`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/phpunit.xml) in the source code.

```
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Looks like I followed the Laravel upgrade guide but it didn't explicitly mention this change.

Comment: @JoshRainwater do not worry, next time, try to see exactly all the source code (changes from version to version), so you can see anything they did not mention (sometimes happens). You only learn this by experience.